OpenSearch - How to calculate number of documents created by Transform Job?
I wonder how to count entries created with Transform Job.
Background
Let's say I have an index with alerts containing, among others, two fields: User ID and Server ID the user operates on. One user can operate on multiple servers. i.e.
{id: ..., user: "Mark", server: "hostname-1"}
{id: ..., user: "John", server: "hostname-2"}
{id: ..., user: "Mark", server: "hostname-2"}
{id: ..., user: "Mark", server: "hostname-2"}

(note the last two entries: it is possible that I have mutltiple entries for the same User and Server)
I need to calculate:

How many distinctive servers are there;
how many distinctive users operated on specific server.

What I did
What I did so far is I created a Transform Job which runs continuously. It removes duplicated entries by grouping user and server fields:
PUT _/plugins/_transform/user_server
  "transform": {
    "enabled": true,
    "continuous": true,
    "schedule": {
      "interval": {
        "period": 1,
        "unit": "Minutes",
        "start_time": 1718277152
      }
    },
    "description": "Getting unique user-server combinations",
    "source_index": "alerts",
    "target_index": "alerts-groups",
    "page_size": 300,
    "groups": [
      {
        "terms": {
          "source_field": "user",
          "target_field": "user"
        }
      },
      {
        "terms": {
          "source_field": "server",
          "target_field": "server"
        }
      },
    ]
  }

Calculating the number of distinctive servers should be as easy as search with aggregation and reading the doc_count value:
GET alerts-groups/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "servers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "server"
      }
    }
  }
}

The Problem
Turns out the doc_count of each bucket does not hold the number of alerts-groups documents, but the number of alerts documents matching each bucket. That's because the Transform Job appends _doc_count field to each generated document, which is then used by aggregation to calculate final doc_count.
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    ...
    "hits": [
      {
        ...
        "_index": "alerts-groups",
        "_source": {
          "transform._id": "user_server",
          "_doc_count": 2,
          "transform._doc_count": 2,
          "server": "hostname-2",
          "user": "Mark"
        }
      },
      {
        ...
        "_index": "alerts-groups",
        "_source": {
          "transform._id": "user_server",
          "_doc_count": 1,
          "transform._doc_count": 1,
          "server": "hostname-2",
          "user": "John"
        }
      },
      ...  // Similar entry for "Mark" and "hostname-1"
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "servers": {
      "buckets": [
        ...
        {
          "key": "hostname-2",
          "doc_count": 3  // expected 2 since there's one entry for Mark and one for John
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

The Question
Is there a way to calculate actual number of documents inserted by Transform Job?
References:

Terms - OpenSearch Documentation
[BUG] Add _doc_count in root of transform documents · Issue #556 · opensearch-project/index-management · GitHub

